# Correct LL(1) grammar for arithmetic expressions

Tags: parsing, compiler-construction, interpreter

This is a correct LL grammar:

> E->TX
>
> T->(E)Y |intY
>
> X->+E | -E | e
>
> Y->*E | /E| e

but it 'll produce the same AST tree for expressions

> int-int+int and int-(int+int)

e.q

> Sub(Simple(int),Add(Simple(int),Simple(int))

Of course, I can use some lookahead, but this isn't cool.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try this grammer

```
E  -> T E'
E' -> + T E' | -TE' |epsilon
T  -> F T'
T' -> * F T' | /FT' |epsilon
F  -> (E) | int
```

Comment: I tried it on paper. Actually,it's the same as the grammar I 've written above. Isn't it?

Comment: No actual its not. Parenthesis dosen't have highest precedence in your grammar. Check it carefully please

Comment: This grammar seems correct. It's exaclty what I was looking for. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Solved this problem by adding some additional "if-s" on evaluating AST. The grammar remains the same